# functionality of hide and reset not working properly

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am working on hiding a series when clicked on legend of googlecharts.
Issue is when i add a extra column which is used to show the tooltip on the bar, the functionality is breaking.
Please find the demo's below:

Not working with extra column added : https://plnkr.co/edit/qXY4Lw4P2N8hNGTg9blv?p=preview

Working code: https://plnkr.co/edit/gRxEgboZCgAkkQ8XfOsr?p=preview

js code:

```
angular.module('myApp', ['googlechart'])
  .controller('myController', function($scope) {
    var chart1 = {};
    chart1.type = "ColumnChart";
    chart1.displayed = false; 
    var myTooltip = {
        role: "tooltip", 
        type: "string"
    };
    chart1.data = {
      "cols": [{
        id: "month",
        label: "Month",
        type: "string"
      }, {
        id: "laptop-id", 
        label: "Laptop",
        type: "number"
      },myTooltip, {
        id: "desktop-id",
        label: "Desktop",
        type: "number"
      }, {
        id: "server-id",
        label: "Server", 
        type: "number"
      }, {
        id: "cost-id",
        label: "Shipping",
        type: "number"
      }],
      "rows": [ {
        c: [{
          v: "Jan"
        }, {
          v: 13
        },{
          v: "laptop tooltip bar1"
        }, {
          v: 1,
          f: "1 unit (Out of stock this month)"
        }, {
          v: 12
        }, { 
          v: 2
        }]
      } ,{
        c: [{
          v: "February"
        }, {
          v: 13
        },{
          v: "laptop tooltip bar2"
        }, {
          v: 1,
          f: "1 unit (Out of stock this month)"
        }, {
          v: 12 
        }, { 
          v: 2
        }]
      }, {
        c: [{
            v: "March"
          }, {
            v: 24
          },{
          v: "laptop tooltip bar3"
        }, {
            v: 5
          }, {
            v: 11
          }, {
            v: 6
          }

        ]
      }]
    };
    chart1.options = {
      "title": "Sales per month",
      "colors": ['#0000FF', '#009900', '#CC0000', '#DD9900'],
      "defaultColors": ['#0000FF', '#009900', '#CC0000', '#DD9900'],
      "isStacked": "true",
      "fill": 20,
      "displayExactValues": true,
      tooltip: {textStyle: {fontName: '"Arial"', bold: "true", fontSize: "14"}},
      "vAxis": {
        "title": "Sales unit",
        "gridlines": {
          "count": 10
        }
      },
      "hAxis": {
        "title": "Date"
      }
    };
    chart1.view = {
      columns: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4,5]
    };
    $scope.myChart = chart1; 

    var hidden = [];
  $scope.reset = function() {
        for (var i = 0; i < hidden.length; i++) {
            var hiddenCol = hidden[i];
            $scope.myChart.view.columns[hiddenCol] = hiddenCol;
            $scope.myChart.options.colors[hiddenCol - 1] = $scope.myChart.options.defaultColors[hiddenCol - 1];

        }
        hidden = [];
    };

    $scope.seriesSelected = function(selectedItem) { 
      if (selectedItem.row === null) {
            var col = selectedItem.column;
            var colIndex = hidden.indexOf(col);
             if (hidden.length === ($scope.myChart.view.columns.length  -3 ) && colIndex == -1) {
                window.alert("One seies of data should be available all time");
            }
            else{
                if(colIndex == -1){
                    hidden.push(col);
                }
                else{
                    hidden.splice(colIndex, 1);
                }
                if ($scope.myChart.view.columns[col] == col) {
                    $scope.myChart.view.columns[col] = {
                        label: $scope.myChart.data.cols[col].label,
                        type: $scope.myChart.data.cols[col].type,
                        //hiding the series.
                        calc: function() {
                            return null;
                        }
                    };
                    //grey color for the hidden data.
                    $scope.myChart.options.colors[col - 1] = '#CCCCCC';
                }
                else {
                    $scope.myChart.view.columns[col] = col;
                    $scope.myChart.options.colors[col - 1] = $scope.myChart.options.defaultColors[col - 1];
                }
            }
        }  

    };
  });
```

Any suggestions? Issue exists When there is extra column(ex: to show tooltip) and that column is not showing in the legend.

Comment: I'm watching it

Comment: Ok so far I found you have a "test3" value in the last row, I suppose it should be 24

Comment: checking $scope.seriesSelected

Comment: The colors array is not syncronized with the column indexes, since you added that tooltip on index 2

Comment: I could've already solve the problem, but I'm trying to find a more generic approach that should work with any future tooltip or column

Comment: @Daniel - Yes, issue exists when extra columns are added like tooltip and annotations but are not shown in the legends..colors array is not synchronized as i have not given any color for tooltip.

Comment: Then you should give it a color, since tooltips are treated as columns it's better that way then doing calculations in the select listener

Comment: @Daniel - I tried giving color to tooltip, still it is not working. Please find the demo https://plnkr.co/edit/gqt8513vZcswI90XFuTv?p=preview

Comment: solved! gonna post the answer

Comment: @Daniel - Can you please post the answer.

Comment: Answer finished!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The problem is not in the chart itself, but its in the colors!**

In google charts, **tooltips are treaten as columns** they have a related index in the columns definition, since we now have a tooltip as the 3rd column *(i.e with the index `2`)* the color indexes are not synchronized with the column ones, so columns after the tooltip are getting a color with the same index of that column minus 2 *(i.e `col - 2` instead of `col - 1`)*.

We can visualize the issue by just imagining both `color` and `column` arrays stacked, like this:

### `index:    0    |   1   |    2    |   3   |   4   |   5`

### `columns: col-x | col1  | tooltip1| col2  |  col3 | col4`

### `colors:  color1| color2| color3  | color4|  ---- | ----`

If we make pairs like `column1 - color1`.. `columnN - colorN`, and group all the `columns without color` *(i.e `col-x` and `tooltip1` in this case)*, we can see that the column's color index should be the `[column's index] - [num of (columns without color) before column's index]`, for example, the color's index for `col1` should be `1 - 1 === 0`, for col2: `3 - 2 === 1`, etc..

Taking this into account, we can easily solve this problem by just creating a variable, `var colorIndex = 0`, incrementing and assigning it for each `column with color` in the column's definition:

```js
"cols": [
    {
        id: "month",
        label: "Month",
        type: "string"
    }, 
    {
        id: "laptop-id",
        label: "Laptop",
        type: "number",
        colorIndex: colorIndex++
    }, 
    {
        role: "tooltip",
        type: "string",
        p: {
            'html': true
        }
    }, 
    {
        id: "desktop-id",
        label: "Desktop",
        type: "number",
        colorIndex: colorIndex++
    }, 
    {
        id: "server-id",
        label: "Server",
        type: "number",
        colorIndex: colorIndex++
    }, 
    {
        id: "cost-id",
        label: "Shipping",
        type: "number",
        colorIndex: colorIndex++
    }
]
```

Then using the colum's `.colorIndex` created property to get the corresponding color:

```
$scope.myChart.options.colors[colorIndex] = $scope.myChart.options.defaultColors[colorIndex];
```

[See the Solution *Plunker*](https://plnkr.co/edit/EhuBhCKkJ3GQrs5mxUdI?p=preview)

Comment: Its working, thanks for explaining in detail which will be very useful for future SO users for this scenario :).